# How to create a table with as many columns as a random csv has? in python

Tags: python, csv, sqlite

is there a way to create a table with as many columns as a random csv has?

So for example if you call the function with a csv that has 3 columns (name, age, height), it creates a table with these three columns.

And if you call the function with a csv that has 5 columns (food, drinks, sports, hobby, name) you get a table with these 5 columns.

Comment: What code have you written so far to attempt to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can

```
import csv, sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cur = con.cursor()

with open('data.csv','rb') as fin:
    dr = csv.DictReader(fin) # comma is default delimiter
    headers = tuple(dr.fieldnames)
cur.execute(f"CREATE TABLE test_t {headers};") # use your column names here
con.close()
```

Comment: Please do not help people that show no effort of trying themselves. It does not really help them, as they learn nothing from it.

Comment: You never know if person has put effort or not. Maybe he is stuck or never worked with this technology and needs answers fast. And they do learn from it.

Comment: The user did not post any code that indicated they might have attempted the problem, and their profile indicates they are a student. Unless users understand what the code is doing and/or they go and read the documentation, I am dubious that they learn more than that SO makes it easy to get someone else to do your work for you.